# clustered mysql servers re-synching after cnx lost

Tags: mysql, sql, synchronization

We are creating an application where there will be a master server, but our clients will also have a server in the office which may lose connection to the main server.  We are studying how to configure MySQL so that 1) the writes are to the master across the internet normally, and the slave is just passively pulling down 2) if connection is lost with the internet/outside world, reads and writes are done on the local server in the office that has access, and 3) when connection is restored, a synch-up is done that works flawlessly

One small hitch is that there might be 2 or 3 of these slave servers, so the synch has to be robust enough for multiple servers.

Consider that before the net connections went down, you had three servers with a contacts table with 100 records.  In the most complex scenario, a new record is added in all 3 locations.  The reconnection process would recognize records unsynched, and after the process is done each table would have 103 records, AND the primary keys re-ordered!

Add to that cascading updates on foreign keys - any suggestions on where to head in the right direction on this?  I'm considering writing a PHP routine for this, but don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally going to be a very difficult architecture to design, test, and maintain. I would *strongly* recommend that you reconsider whether partition tolerance (specifically, the ability to allow writes to a database that is not connected to the master) is required for your design.

If this is absolutely necessary, several gotchas you will need to deal with will include:

- You will need to stop using `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary keys entirely, as it is next to impossible to safely synchronize them after a split, as the same key may have been used by multiple servers, and the key may be present in locations that you cannot update after the fact (for instance, in URLs!). Generate primary keys either by using an offset for each server (e.g, server A uses IDs `100`, `200`, `300`, server B uses `101`, `201`, `301`, etc), or by using GUID primary keys so that conflicts should never occur at all.

  Note that GUID primary keys have a pronounced negative impact on MySQL server performance, as they make an absolute mess of the index. Proceed with caution.
- If you thought synchronizing updates to the database was difficult, handling updates and deletes will make that look easy by comparison. One workaround may be to avoid updates and deletes entirely — treat each table as a "journal", insert a new row each time the state of an object changes (including when it is deleted), and treat the most recent row for an identifier as the "current state". This will make any sort of relational operations on your database basically impossible (as it is very difficult to perform any sort of useful JOIN on such a table!), but it will at least simplify the task of synchronization.

  If that isn't possible, the situation starts to look pretty grim. You will may end up needing to maintain a journal of all changes made while your network is not fully connected, and reconcile those journals every time a server reconnects. This will likely not scale very well.

  Keep in mind as well that any automated conflict resolution will likely result in some data loss or unexpected results. In particular, if a single field of a record is updated by both sides of a network split, your synchronization tools will need to either pick one of the new values to "win", or to somehow merge those values. Depending on what the field is and what it represents, this may be very difficult or even impossible. (For a particularly bad example, consider what happens if a field represents a user's bank account balance, and an update on one side is lost in synchronization!)

If these topics are at all of interest to you, you may want to research some of the underlying theory. Several concepts of particular interest will be:

- The [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), which essentially says that it's impossible to have a fault-tolerant system without compromises.
- [Vector clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock), which are one method of synchronizing changes to individual objects in a distributed system
- [Bourbon whiskey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbon_whiskey), which will ease your pains trying to debug this system.

**TL;DR: partition tolerance is hard.** Really, really hard. Avoid having to deal with it if at all possible.